# if conditions is false then prevent default in SharePoint 2010 List new form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

```
The SharePoint 2010 List new form has 10 checkboxes. I want to select only 3 (also not less than) of them.
I used jquery for this but when condition is false then form does not stop doing submit action.
```

HTML:

```
<TD><SPAN class=ms-RadioText title=One>
<INPUT id=ctl00_m_g_69fc6715_3136_4421_a83a_06892e860a7a_ff21_ctl00_ctl00 type=checkbox name=ctl00$m$g_69fc6715_3136_4421_a83a_06892e860a7a$ff21$ctl00$ctl00></SPAN></TD>
```

similarly there are 10 TD element.

Save Button:

```
<INPUT accessKey=O id=ctl00_m_g_69fc6715_3136_4421_a83a_06892e860a7a_savebutton2_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem class=ms-ButtonHeightWidth onclick='if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$g_69fc6715_3136_4421_a83a_06892e860a7a$savebutton2$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem", "", true, "", "", false, true))' value=Save type=button name=ctl00$m$g_69fc6715_3136_4421_a83a_06892e860a7a$savebutton2$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem target="_self" jQuery1372914969010="1">

jquery: 

$("#ctl00_m_g_69fc6715_3136_4421_a83a_06892e860a7a_savebutton2_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem").click(function() {

    if($('.ms-RadioText input:checked').length!=3) // ms-RadioText is a class
       {
           alert("You have to select any 3 options");
            e.preventDefault();
            e.returnvalue=false // for IE only
            return false; 
       }
});
```

I used all three options (and also one by one) to prevent the submit action but no result.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the event in the function, otherwise your variable `e` will be undefined

```
$("#ctl00_m_g_69fc6715_3136_4421_a83a_06892e860a7a_savebutton2_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem").click(function(e) {

    if($('.ms-RadioText input:checked').length!=3)
       {
           alert("You have to select any 3 options");
            e.preventDefault();
            e.returnvalue=false // for IE only
            return false; 
       }
});
```

**[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sfq2L/)**

if that doesn't work, check your html code and add the double quotations around the attributes values e.g. `attrib="value"` to ensure correct syntax

I gotta ask, what is with the long id ?

Comment: I did that, added e in the function but still it does not work. This is SharePoint List form so it automatically created that id. As it is SharePoint form, I can not change the value of attrib.

Comment: dude something is wrong with your button, you should not have an onclick in it ! since you add the handler in the jquery

Comment: no onclick attribute setting from both sides, the local one will win! `<INPUT accessKey=O id=ctl00_m_g_69fc6715_3136_4421_a83a_06892e860a7a_savebutton2_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem class=ms-ButtonHeightWidth value=Save type=button name=ctl00$m$g_69fc6715_3136_4421_a83a_06892e860a7a$savebutton2$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem target="_self" jQuery1372914969010="1">`

Comment: yes just remove the onclick from the button itself and the jquery will add that function that will handle it ,, check the fiddle I added in my answer, and don't forget to add all that jquery code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ /* your code*/});`

Comment: No it is not resolving. I checked your fiddle where you had removed onlick function of button itself. But as this is SharePoint I cannot do like that ... when I tried something like this                             $("#ctl00_m_g_69fc6715_3136_4421_a83a_06892e860a7a_savebutton2_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem").attr('onclick','').unbind('click');       it stop to work both functions.

Comment: embed that code in the function I created for the onclick event, it has to be in there not in the button if you need it.